# Langchain OpenAIEmbeddings resource not found (404) with AzureOpenAI credentials

Tags: langchain, azure-openai, openaiembeddings, langchain-js

I'm having trouble using LangChain embedding with Azure OpenAI credentials - it's showing a 404 error for resource not found.

```
stack trace: Error: 404 Resource not found
    at APIError.generate (c:\abcproject\node_modules\openai\error.js:53:20
```

```
import { OpenAIEmbeddings } from "@langchain/openai"

export const embeddingModel = new OpenAIEmbeddings({ 
  azureOpenAIApiKey: "AzureOpenAI api key",
  azureOpenAIApiVersion: "2023-08-01-preview",
  azureOpenAIApiDeploymentName: "gpt-4-32k",
  azureOpenAIBasePath:"Azure OpenAI endpoint"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of your `OpenAIEmbeddings` class is incorrect: you should not have something related to `gpt` models for embeddings, but "text-embedding-ada-002" instead.

Try modifying your `azureOpenAIApiDeploymentName` value or better use `modelName` (see [doc](https://api.js.langchain.com/interfaces/langchain_openai.OpenAIEmbeddingsParams.html#modelName))

Comment: I deployed text-embedding-ada-002 on azure and i added  azureOpenAIApiDeploymentName as  text-embedding-ada-002 but still getting same 404 error . 

`
  export const embeddingModel = new OpenAIEmbeddings({
    azureOpenAIApiKey: "my azure openai api key",
    azureOpenAIApiVersion: "2022-12-01",
    azureOpenAIApiDeploymentName:"text-embedding-ada-002",
    azureOpenAIBasePath: "https://abc.openai.azure.com/",
});
`

Comment: check the end of my response: use 'modelName'